# UINavigationController - how to change animation for single UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

How can I have custom animation only for single `UIViewController` push/pop and default animation for other `UIViewControllers` in same `UINavigationController`?

I use `UINavigationController` and push/pop to navigate between different UIViewControllers. I created custom animation and set custom `UINavigationControllerDelegate` to `UINavigationController.delegate`. It animates fine but it changes animation style for all future push/pop in this `UINavigationController`.

I know I can change animation for single `UIViewController` using it's transitioningDelegate but it works only if it's displayed by present() and not push.
Is it possible to change animation only for single `UIViewController` in `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for specific view controller from navigation controller like:

UINavigationcontroller.ViewControllers[number of that view controller]

and apply that animation on it.

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean. I set delegate and then push like this to apply animation
navigationController.delegate = customOpenDetailAnimationDelegate
navigationController.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)
It changes animation for detailViewController but if i do next call ie navigationController.pushViewController(anotherViewController, animated: true) it contains same animation, but I want default one

Comment: what i'm saying is really simple might be helpful for you simply while pushing with different animation check weither the view controller is your desirable if not then don't apply while pushing.if i am getting it right..

Answer (score 0):

Sub class `UINavigationController` and use `CoreAnimation's` transition to change push/pop animations like this.

```
enum TransitionType {
    case fade
    case movein
    case push
    case reveal
}
enum TransitionSubtype {
    case right
    case left
    case top
    case bottom
}

class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    fileprivate func getTransition(by type: TransitionType) -> String? {
        var transition: String?
        switch type {
        case .fade:
            transition = kCATransitionFade
            break
        case .push:
            transition = kCATransitionPush
            break
        case .movein:
            transition = kCATransitionMoveIn
            break
        case .reveal:
            transition = kCATransitionReveal
            break
        default:
            transition = nil
            break
        }
        return transition
    }
    fileprivate func getSubTransition(by type: TransitionSubtype) -> String? {
        var transition: String?
        switch type {
        case .right:
            transition = kCATransitionFromRight
            break
        case .left:
            transition = kCATransitionFromLeft
            break
        case .top:
            transition = kCATransitionFromTop
            break
        case .bottom:
            transition = kCATransitionFromBottom
            break
        default:
            transition = nil
            break
        }
        return transition
    }

    func display(viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool, animationType: TransitionType = .push, animationSubtype: TransitionSubtype = .left) -> Bool {
        guard  let type = getTransition(by: animationType) else {return false}
        guard  let subtype = getSubTransition(by: animationSubtype) else {return false}
        if animated {
            let transition = CATransition()
            transition.duration = 0.35
            transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
            transition.type = type
            transition.subtype = subtype
            self.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
        }
        _ = self.pushViewController(viewController, animated: false)
        return true
    }
    func hide(animated: Bool, animationType: TransitionType = .push, animationSubtype: TransitionSubtype = .left) -> Bool {
        guard  let type = getTransition(by: animationType) else {return false}
        guard  let subtype = getSubTransition(by: animationSubtype) else {return false}
        if animated {
            let transition = CATransition()
            transition.duration = 0.35
            transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
            transition.type = type
            transition.subtype = subtype
            self.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
        }
        _ = self.popViewController(animated: false)
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Problem with this is CATransition. It animates but issue is that CATransition has unwanted fade effect which is impossible to disable. Because of this I don't use CATransition.